# The user or group name 'domain\group' is not recognized. SSRS 2017

Tags: reporting-services

What are possible sources of this error message when trying to add an item level role to a group in SSRS 2017? I have tried removing and re-adding the server to the domain to see if that helps recognize the group. I have ensured that the group is a security group and not a distribution group. The group also has universal or global scope.

Answer (score 0):

This was an old domain group that had a Name that was different then the login name(pre-windows 2000). I had to use the login name(pre-windows 2000) to be able to add an item level role to the group successfully.

Comment: A group does not have a "login name".

Comment: Technically it is called a "logon" name if thats what you mean. See link. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ad/getting-the-domain-account-style-name-of-a-group